# excel to xml--Showing some error correct me\

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, excel, exe

I have 3 excel files ,and each excel files contains certain amount of data.and each excel files are joined by a column, Here My problem is Want to get a xml file from excel files.

First excel sheet contains following information-excel name -Employees

### emp id ||empname||compid||departid

500    ||xxx    ||01    || A

501    ||yyy    ||02    ||B

Second excel sheet contains following information-excel name -Company

### Compid  || compname ||Location

01  || YYY      || Ktpna

02      || 02-YYY   || Thdpza

Third excel sheet contains following information-excel name -Department

### Departid || Departname || Location|| Teamleader

A    || A-AAA      ||A-Ktpna  || A-XXX

B    || B-AAA      ||B-Thdpza || B-YYY

I want to get a XMl Output like

```
<employeesInformation>
<Employees>
<emp id> 500 </emp id>
<empname> xxx </empname>
<compid> 01 </compid>
<departid> A </departid>
</Employees>
<Company>
<Compid> 01 </Compid>
<compname> YYY </compname>
<Location> Ktpna </Location> 
</Company>
<Department>
<Departid >A<Departid>
<Departname> A-AAA  <Departname>
<Location>A-Ktpna<Location>
<Teamleader> A-XXX<Teamleader>
</Department>
<employeesInformation>

<employeesInformation>
<Employees>
<emp id> 501 </emp id>
<empname> yyy </empname>
<compid> 02 </compid>
<departid> B </departid>
</Employees>
<Company>
<Compid> 02 </Compid>
<compname> 02-YYY </compname>
<Location> Thdpza </Location> 
</Company>
<Department>
<Departid >B<Departid>
<Departname> B-AAA  <Departname>
<Location>B-Thdpza <Location>
<Teamleader> B-YYY<Teamleader>
</Department>
<employeesInformation>
```

and using following  code

```
  private DataTable ReadExcelFile(string filename)
        {
            // Initialize an instance of DataTable
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                // Use SpreadSheetDocument class of Open XML SDK to open excel file
                using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, false))
                {
                    // Get Workbook Part of Spread Sheet Document
                    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;

                    // Get all sheets in spread sheet document 
                    IEnumerable<Sheet> sheetcollection = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();

                    // Get relationship Id
                    string relationshipId = sheetcollection.First().Id.Value;

                    // Get sheet1 Part of Spread Sheet Document
                    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);

                    // Get Data in Excel file
                    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
                    IEnumerable<Row> rowcollection = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();

                    if (rowcollection.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        return dt;
                    }

                    // Add columns
                    foreach (Cell cell in rowcollection.ElementAt(0))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(GetValueOfCell(spreadsheetDocument, cell));
                    }

                    // Add rows into DataTable
                    foreach (Row row in rowcollection)
                    {
                        DataRow temprow = dt.NewRow();
                        int columnIndex = 0;
                        foreach (Cell cell in row.Descendants<Cell>())
                        {
                            // Get Cell Column Index
                            int cellColumnIndex = GetColumnIndex(GetColumnName(cell.CellReference));

                            if (columnIndex < cellColumnIndex)
                            {
                                do
                                {
                                    temprow[columnIndex] = string.Empty;
                                    columnIndex++;
                                }

                                while (columnIndex < cellColumnIndex);
                            }

                            temprow[columnIndex] = GetValueOfCell(spreadsheetDocument, cell);
                            columnIndex++;
                        }

                        // Add the row to DataTable
                        // the rows include header row
                        dt.Rows.Add(temprow);
                    }
                }

                // Here remove header row
                dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
                return dt;
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                throw new IOException(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```